# Tools to create EAR files

Tags: ejb

I am new to EJB, I would like to know a tool to configure my EJB and create EAR files.

I know, using Eclipse and Netbeans it is possible, instead I want to use some standalone tools to create EAR files.

Please provide some link or documentation to do this step by step.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has plugins that will create EAR files for you.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

Comment: Maven is part of Eclipse is it? I am looking for a standalone tool to do this.

Comment: Maven is not part of eclipse.  Maven is a stand along tool